# How to override max length of username in Django by creating a custom model

Tags: python, django, inheritance, migration, maxlength

I have a problem. I'm using Django 1.7, and have already made a custom user model, that inherits Django's abstract user like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, BaseModel):
```

Now they say in here [Django-ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20846), that I could avoid the problem of username's max_length being 30, by creating a custom user. Well, I already have a custom user, so it should be easy right? How I tried to do it was:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, BaseModel):

      username = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True, db_index=True)
```

Now when I try to make migrations for changing this field, it results in an error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'username' in class 'CustomUser' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'`

What am I doing wrong? How could I solve this problem? I have data that should be migrated, so I cannot empty database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to be more flexible inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` instead, you will be able to specify your own username field that way, e.g.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_('date created'),
        auto_created=True,
        default=timezone.now
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Tried this. So I changed inheritance to AbstractBaseUser, created email field, and defined USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'. Then I tried to create migrations, but it resulted in: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (first_name, last_name, is_active, is_superuser, is_staff, groups, user_permissions) specified for CustomUser. I guess I just have to copy those fields from AbstractUser model to my own model?

Comment: Yes you can copy all your mandatory fields to the custom user class you have defined

Comment: That would require quite a lot of copying from different django base classes, are you sure that would be the best option?

Comment: Shouldn't "User" be your base class anyway? You can use the mixin principle if you don't want to declare them explicitly on the model

Comment: I mean besides some fields,  I would have to also inherit the PermissionsMixin, and from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _. I could try that, but it's just quite a lot, and I wonder if there would be some other solution mm...

Comment: instead of `AbstractBaseUser` use `AbstractUser`

Answer (score 8):

Dont try to override `username` field. Just

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, BaseModel):

       #here goes other fields

CustomUser._meta.get_field('username').max_length = 70
```

But I highly recommend to [inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`](http://procrastinatingdev.com/django/using-configurable-user-models-in-django-1-5/) instead.

Comment: As a side question, do you know what the '_meta' does?

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja is used to retrieve "meta data" like fields, etc,  from model.

Comment: Why is it better to inherit from AbstractBaseUser if this is the only change you want to make? (Still wrapping my head around this problem)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you can't override any Django ORM model's attribute, nor from `AbstractUser`, nor from `PermissionsMixin` classes. So, If you have your own approach to Permissions, Groups(Roles), even if you want another attribute name than `user_permissions` or `groups`, then you should inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`, doing a lot of copy-paste from `AbstractUser` and inherit your `Permission` and `Group` models from `django.db.models.Model` class as **@levi** and **@Hedde van der Heide** suggested.